# Create a select statement that returns a record for each day after a given created date

Tags: sql-server

I have a Dimension table containing machines. 
Each machine has a date created value.

I would like to have a Select statement that generates for each day after a certain start date the available number of machines. A machine is available after the date created on wards

As I have read only access to the database I am not able to create a physical calendar table

I hope somebody can help me solving my issue

Comment: yes, check out this article. https://riptutorial.com/sql-server/example/11099/generating-a-date-range-with-a-tally-table

Comment: @Jeremy, not that you wrote it or anything, but there's a typo in the script in that link. The final cross-join should be to E4, not E2. Knowing that, though, I might just save the link anyway so I can stop Googling "Ben-Gan tally script". Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume this is what you want. Based on this sample table:

```
USE tempdb;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.Machines
(
    MachineID int,
    CreatedDate date
);

INSERT dbo.Machines VALUES(1,'20200104'),(2,'20200202'),(3,'20200214');
```

Then say you wanted the number of active machines starting on January 1st:

```
DECLARE @StartDate date = '20200101';

;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT n = 0 UNION ALL SELECT n + 1 FROM x 
    WHERE n < DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, GETDATE())
),
days(d) AS 
(
  SELECT DATEADD(DAY, x.n, @StartDate) FROM x
)
SELECT days.d, MachineCount = COUNT(m.MachineID) 
  FROM days 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Machines AS m
  ON days.d >= m.CreatedDate
  GROUP BY days.d
  ORDER BY days.d
  OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

Results:

```
d            MachineCount
----------   ------------
2020-01-01   0
2020-01-02   0
2020-01-03   0
2020-01-04   1
2020-01-05   1
...
2020-01-31   1
2020-02-01   1
2020-02-02   2
2020-02-03   2
...
2020-02-12   2
2020-02-13   2
2020-02-14   3
2020-02-15   3
```

Clean up:

```
DROP TABLE dbo.Machines;
```

(Yes, some people hiss at recursive CTEs. You can replace it with any number of set generation techniques, some I talk about [here](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1), [here](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-2), and [here](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-3).)

Comment: Hi Aaron, Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was looking for and it works :)

Comment: @user3762792 approve the answer to let know that it has been solved